# How to best include field from Django ManyToManyField custom intermediary model when using prefetch_related?

Tags: django, optimization, django-orm

Models:

```
class User(models.Model):
    teams = models.ManyToManyField('Team', through='TeamMember', related_name='members')

class Team(models.Model):
    pass

class TeamMember(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    team = models.ForeignKey(Team, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    position = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

I am trying to build a queryset that will fetch users and (running another query with prefetch_related) teams for those users with `TeamMember.position` included as one of the fields on the team without running any unnecessary queries or joins.

Here is the queryset I have so far:

```
User.objects.prefetch_related(Prefetch('teams', queryset=Team.objects.annotate(position=F('teammember__position'))))
```

But it is doing an unnecessary join:

```
SELECT `appname_user`.`id` FROM `appname_user` LIMIT 21; args=()
SELECT (`appname_teammember`.`user_id`) AS `_prefetch_related_val_user_id`, `appname_team`.`id`, `appname_teammember`.`position` AS `position` FROM `appname_team` LEFT OUTER JOIN `appname_teammember` ON (`appname_team`.`id` = `appname_teammember`.`team_id`) INNER JOIN `appname_teammember` T3 ON (`appname_team`.`id` = T3.`team_id`) WHERE T3.`user_id` IN (1); args=(1,)
```

It is joining appname_teammember twice when it doesn't need to. Anyone know how to eliminate that extra join?